# Jquery UI Sortable Tabs that Sort the Content as well as the tab

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, jquery-ui

The jQuery docs and examples quite clearly show me how to sort tabs:
https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

BUT... my requirement is to change the actual HTML of the DOM so that the order of the content windows changes with the sortable action.

So my HTML in the DOM looks like this:

```
<ul> 
    <li><a href="#c1">Tab 1</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#c2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#c3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#c4">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="c1">CONTENT TAB 1</div>
<div id="c2">CONTENT TAB 2</div>
<div id="c3">CONTENT TAB 3</div>
<div id="c4">CONTENT TAB 4</div>
```

Then if I use the `sortable` action to swap #2 and #3 around, I get this:

```
<ul> 
    <li><a href="#c1">Tab 1</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#c3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#c2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#c4">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Which is lovely, but the content DIV remains the same, for my application I want to latch this tab sort to the content such that my Content HTML becomes:

```
<div id="c1">CONTENT TAB 1</div>
<div id="c3">CONTENT TAB 3</div>
<div id="c2">CONTENT TAB 2</div>
<div id="c4">CONTENT TAB 4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I have it in case anyone else wants to know, you can do this:

```
var i_tabs = $('#tab_div').tabs();
var dragstart_i;
i_tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").sortable({
    axis: "x",
    start: function (e, ui) {
        dragstart_i= $(ui.item[0]).index();
    },
    stop: function (e, ui) {
        var i = $(ui.item[0]).index();
        var new_index;
        if (dragstart_i > i) {
            new_index = i;
        } else {
            new_index = i + 1;
        };
        var content = $('#slide_' + extractNumbers($(ui.item[0]).attr('id'))); // .remove(); 
        $(content).insertBefore($("#slider_images > div")[new_index]);
        i_tabs.tabs("refresh");
    }
});
```